# CSS counter-increment with different scopes

Tags: html, css

I need to create a continuous enumeration in different order list of the document.

The HTML is generated dynamically and cannot be modified.

I have the following structure and CSS:

```css
body{
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol.instructions:not(.continue){
    counter-reset: item;
}
li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item) ".";
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions continue">
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <ol class="instructions continue">
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 8</li>
        <li>item 9</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <ol class="instructions continue">
        <li>item 10</li>
        <li>item 11</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 12</li>
        <li>item 13</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

The selector `.instructions` starts a new count, but `.instructions.continue` must continue with previous counting.

The result should be:

```
1. item 1
2. item 2
3. item 3
4. item 4
5. item 5
6. item 6
7. item 7
1. item 8
2. item 9
3. item 10
4. item 11
1. item 12
2. item 13
```

Comment: `ol.instructions:not(.continue){ counter-set: item 0; }` would do the job here, I think … but that currently only works in Firefox.

Comment: @CBroe yes! only in firefox, but we have something...

Answer (score 1):

Please use all `ol` in `col` div.

```css
body{
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol.instructions:not(.continue){
    counter-reset: item;
}
li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item) ".";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="col">
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions continue">
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions continue">
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 8</li>
        <li>item 9</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions continue">
        <li>item 10</li>
        <li>item 11</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 12</li>
        <li>item 13</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: please try this @jonycleva. You are used some ol in different col div it make counter

Comment: Thanks @Rayees AC! Yes, that will be a solution, but the structure cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1):

I find this possible solution preserving a general structure and global variables and selectors.

Thanks for all the comments and recommendations.
I hope all the answers and comments help those with similar problems.

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    
}

ol.instructions:not(.continue){
    counter-reset: item;    
}

ol.instructions.continue{
    counter-reset: itemC var(--lastC);
}

ol.instructions.continue li::before {
  content: counter(itemC) ".";
  counter-increment: itemC;
}

li::before {
  content: counter(item) ".";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <ol class="instructions">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="instructions continue" style="--lastC:3">
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <ol class="instructions continue" style="--lastC:5">
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="instructions">
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <ol class="instructions continue" style="--lastC:2">
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="instructions">
    <li>item 12</li>
    <li>item 13</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not reset the counter inside the `ol`

```css
body{
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol.instructions:not(.continue){
   /* counter-reset: item;*/
}
li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item) ".";
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions continue">
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <ol class="instructions continue">
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 8</li>
        <li>item 9</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <ol class="instructions continue">
        <li>item 10</li>
        <li>item 11</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 12</li>
        <li>item 13</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

You need to move your `continue` logic to col div

```css
body{
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.col:not(.continue){
   counter-reset: item;
}
li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item) ".";
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions ">
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div class="col continue">
    <ol class="instructions ">
        <li>item 6</li>
        <li>item 7</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 8</li>
        <li>item 9</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div class="col continue">
    <ol class="instructions ">
        <li>item 10</li>
        <li>item 11</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 12</li>
        <li>item 13</li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <ol class="instructions ">
        <li>item 10</li>
        <li>item 11</li>
    </ol>
    <ol class="instructions">
        <li>item 12</li>
        <li>item 13</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanls Temani, in this case all items of colum continue with the counting of previus column, but that is not the case, sometime I need restart the counting in a half of column, not only in the beginning and not for all items in the colum.

Comment: @jonycleva you cannot do this, if you rester the counter inside col then it's dead for you because the scope will change and will no more apply inside another col

Comment: yes, I undertand, but I need restart the counting in a half of column, for exampe ` <li>item 8</li>` in this item.

Comment: @jonycleva sorry but you cannot with this structure, at least with the way you are using counter. You will need something different

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out a way to do it exactly with a single counter.

Here's a way using grouped counters:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: group-one group-two group-three;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.group-one li::before {
  counter-increment: group-one;
  content: counter(group-one) ".";
}

.group-two li::before {
  counter-increment: group-two;
  content: counter(group-two) ".";
}

.group-three li::before {
  counter-increment: group-three;
  content: counter(group-three) ".";
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <ol class="instructions group-one">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="instructions group-one">
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <ol class="instructions group-one">
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="instructions group-two">
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <ol class="instructions group-two">
    <li>item 10</li>
    <li>item 11</li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="instructions group-three">
    <li>item 12</li>
    <li>item 13</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! But the structure can be much bigger. I need resolve the problem with global classes

Comment: I don't think it's possible the way you want to do it. If you use my suggestion, the only way you could make it scalable is building a stylesheet in JS, appending it to the `head`, and adding the relevant classes to each `ol` element.